# Change file (url, path) automatically when clicking button in AVAudioplayer Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, audio, path

3 images per screen, each with distinct sound files "apple.wav", "orange.wav", and "ball.wav" that will play when clicked.

I have the AVAudioPlayer code but I'm trying to simplify it, so I don't have a separate function for each photo `playSoundOrange()`, `playSoundofApple()`, *etc*.

Trying to use the same function, but input the name of the file in the button action.

Button code:

```
@IBAction func OrangeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("pressed OrangeButton")
    playSoundFile(orange.wav) //having it like this would be ideal. 
}
```

Current func I'm trying to modify, so I'm able to use the code `playSoundFile(orange.wav)` for each button, and just change the parameters to (apple.wav) or (ball.wav).

```
var player : AVAudioPlayer?
func playSoundFile(){
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "*orange*",   ofType:"*wav*")!
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    do {
        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        self.player = sound
        sound.numberOfLoops = 0
        sound.prepareToPlay()
        sound.play()
    } catch {
        print("error loading file")
        // couldn't load file :(
    }
}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an outlet for each button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `playSoundFile` method to take a sound name:

```
func playSoundFile(_ soundName: String) {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundName, withExtension: "wav")!

    do {
        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        self.player = sound
        sound.numberOfLoops = 0
        sound.prepareToPlay()
        sound.play()
    } catch {
        print("error loading file")
        // couldn't load file :(
    }
}
```

Now you only need a single button action that you can use for all three buttons.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

Assign that one action to all three buttons.

Since you have an outlet for each button, compare the `sender` property against each of your outlets to determine which filename to use:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var soundName: String? = nil
    if sender == orangeButton {
        soundName = "orange"
    } else if sender == appleButton {
        soundName = "apple"
    } else if sender == ballButton {
        soundName = "ball"
    }

    if let soundName = soundName {
        playSoundFile(soundName)
    }
}
```

Replace `orangeButton`, `appleButton`, and `ballButton` with the actual name of your outlets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks rmaddy, for solving it. Just putting the code in full for other newbies who might benefit from it.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player : AVAudioPlayer?

func playSoundFile(_ soundName: String) {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundName, withExtension: "wav")!

    do {
        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        self.player = sound
        sound.numberOfLoops = 1
        sound.prepareToPlay()
        sound.play()
    } catch {
        print("error loading file")
        // couldn't load file :(
    }
}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var soundName: String? = nil
        if sender.currentTitle == "john" {
            soundName = "john"
        }else if sender.currentTitle == "husain" {
                soundName = "husain"
        }else if sender.currentTitle == "tom" {
                    soundName = "tom"
             }
            if let soundName = soundName {
                playSoundFile(soundName)
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: There really was no reason for you to post the full code. Answers don't need to be complete classes to solve issues and answer questions.